# Android: fill spinner with items in text file

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I want fill spinner with items in text file on my hosting. 
The text file content separate with "\n" character:

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
```

I write this code but I've this error :

```
03-10 12:32:07.716: E/AndroidRuntime(7670): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-69056
03-10 12:32:07.716: 

E/AndroidRuntime(7670): 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
length=91; index=91

                    bo.write(buffer);
                    String s = bo.toString();

                    final Vector<String> str = new Vector<String>();
                    String[] line = s.split("\n");
                    int index = 0;
                    while (line[index] != null) {
                        str.add(line[index]);
                        index++;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the condition..
with this:

```
while (line[index] != null) {
   str.add(line[index]);
   index++;
}
```

if say the size of line is 10, index++ will make it 11.
thus line[11] will not be null but rather throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

change the condition to :

```
for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++) {
    if(line[i] != null) {
       str.add(line[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.
Now the script working correctly but the list country in spinner stopping in country Korea... why?

Comment: may be you could log each line and then find out why it stops at korea?

Comment: I've changed my country txt.

This version stopping to country French Polyn
http://www.filesnack.com/files/ctjlom8p

If use this other txt file http://www.filesnack.com/files/ct9sr3fn the spinner is populated correctly ... ??? :(

Comment: you are using a string buffer, may be the number of characters the buffer can hold is exceeded and hence the truncation of data takes place ?

Comment: yes Sir the buffer is exceeded and the truncation of data takes place

Comment: try specifying a size to the buffer such that it contains all the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be check by the length of your String array in for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++) {
if(line[i] != null) {
   str.add(line[index]);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.
Now the script working correctly but the list country in spinner stopping in country Korea... why?

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
bo.write(buffer);
String s = bo.toString();
final Vector<String> str = new Vector<String>();
String[] line = s.split("\n");
int index = 0;
while (index < line.length) {
str.add(line[index]);
index++;
}
```

You are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are not doing bound checking for line array.

Comment: thank you very much.
Now the script working correctly but the list country in spinner stopping in country Korea... why?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
int index = 0, length = line.length;
while (index < length) {
   str.add(line[index++]);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.
Now the script working correctly but the list country in spinner stopping in country Korea... why?